# How to stop Thread via button?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a button that is supposed to stop a thread that is running a server function on another Python file. The solutions I've tried are as follows:

**Solution #1: Threading.Event**

mainmenu.py

```
import server as serv #as in server.py
import socket
from threading import Thread
import customtkinter as cust


class GUI2(cust.CTk): #second window; not the root
    def __init__(self):
        self.master2 = cust.CTkToplevel()
        self.master2.title("Admin/Host Lobby")
        self.master2.geometry(f"{906}x{400}")
        self.master2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.leavewindow)
        self.leave = cust.CTkButton(self.master2, text = "Leave", fg_color = "Red", text_color = "White", hover_color = "Maroon", command = lambda: self.leavewindow())
        self.leave.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "n", padx = 1, pady = 1)

        self.thread = Thread(target = serv.startChat)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def leavewindow(self):
        serv.terminate() #calls function from server.py that sets flag to true
        self.thread.join() #wait for thread to close
        print("Thread closed")
        serv.commence() #calls function from server.py that sets flag to false in case window is accessed again without exiting the program
        self.master2.destroy()
```

server.py

```
import socket
import threading
import traceback

flag = threading.Event()

PORT = 5000
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDRESS = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"

clients, names = [], []
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDRESS)


def terminate(): #set flag to true
    flag.set()

def commence(): #set flag to false
    flag.clear()

def startChat(): #function that listens for client connections; the aforementioned function I want to stop/break when button is pressed
    print("server is working on " + SERVER)
    server.listen(30)
    try:
        while not flag.is_set(): #function runs as long as flag is not true
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            name = conn.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
            clients.append(conn)
    except:
        print (traceback.format_exc())
```

**Solution #2: Global Flag Variable**

Same code as above but with the following changes:

mainmenu.py

```
def leavewindow(self):
    serv.setFlag(1) #passes integer 1 to set flag to True
    self.thread.join() #wait for thread to close
    print("Thread closed")
    serv.setFlag(0) #passes integer 0 to set flag to false in case window is accessed again without exiting the program
    self.master2.destroy()
```

server.py

```
flag = False
def setFlag(a): #function receives integer to set flag value
    global flag
    if a == 0:
        flag = False
    else:
        flag = True

def startChat(): #function that listens for client connections; the aforementioned function I want to stop/break when button is pressed
    print("server is working on " + SERVER)
    server.listen(30)
    try:
        while True:
            global flag
            if flag:
                break
            else:
                conn, addr = server.accept()
                name = conn.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
                clients.append(conn)
    except:
        print (traceback.format_exc())
```

Both of these "solutions" ends up freezing the window for an indefinite time; no errors printed in the terminal plus the line `print("Thread closed")` isn't even reached.

Any advice or alternative solutions in fixing this bug is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (if not *the*) major cause of an unresponsive `tkinter` GUI is a callback that keeps running.

The only callback that we see is `leavewindow()`.
In that function, basically only `self.thread.join()` can cause this.

By default, sockets are created in blocking mode.
So for example `recv` will wait until it receives data.
Which is not what you want, because your flag or event will not be tested until after data is received.

You could set a timeout on the `conn` socket so it raises an exception when no data is received.
In the handler for that exception, just `sleep()` in the `while`-loop for some milliseconds.

```
def startChat(): #function that listens for client connections; the aforementioned function I want to stop/break when button is pressed
    print("server is working on " + SERVER)
    server.listen(30)
     # Not sure if the following line is needed...
    server.settimeout(0.005) # time out after 5 ms.
    try:
        while not flag.is_set(): # works with global flag as well
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            conn.settimeout(0.005) # time out after 5 ms.
            name = conn.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
            clients.append(conn)
    except socket.timeout:
        time.sleep(0.005)
    except Exception:
        print (traceback.format_exc())
```

Or you could use the `selectors` module with a nonblocking socket to only try and read data if any is available. Here you should also `sleep()` in the `while`-loop for some milliseconds when no data is available.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; the code provided worked. A small clarification for `conn.settimeout` though. Does this mean, in theory, that if the server keeps receiving data every 5 ms, `self.thread.join` will not work and instead freeze the window?

Comment: Further tested, it looks like the code stops working if `server.settimeout(0.005)` is commented out instead of the `conn.settimeout(0.005)`. Is that normal?

Comment: If you don't set a timeout, sockets operate in *blocking mode*. That means that calls like `accept` and `recv` *keep waiting* until the event they expect happens. That is no good if you depend on a thread reacting timely to a call for it to exit. In general, event driven systems like most GUIs and blocking API calls are not a good mix.